# How to append row to specific columns with gspread?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a google sheet with values on it. Think it like this:

| header1 | col1 | header 3 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First |  | row |  |
| Second |  | row |  |

I will have another data that will come and fill the 2nd and 4th  column by respectively.

So what I want to use append_row with specific column name because after each process (my code) I want to immediately add it to my google sheet.

---

WHAT I DO FOR NOW (I want to change this logic):

I have 2 columns like this. So what I have done before after my code completes (all data is ready now) I was adding those data with worksheet update like this (I am using gspread):

```py
        headers = worksheet.row_values(1)
        col1_index = headers.index('col1') + 1
        col2_index = headers.index('col2') + 1



        for item in result:
            col1_list.append(item['col1'])
            col2_list.append(item['col2'])
            

        col1_transposed = [[item] for item in col1_list]
        col2_transposed = [[item] for item in col2_list]


        col1_range = '{}2:{}{}'.format(chr(65 + col1_index - 1), chr(65 + col1_index - 1),
                                                len(col1_list) + 1)

        col2_range = '{}2:{}{}'.format(chr(65 + col2_index - 1), chr(65 + col2_index - 1),
                                                len(col2_list) + 1)


        worksheet.update(col1_range, col1_transposed)
        worksheet.update(col2_range, col2_transposed)
```

But now I want to say like I want to append my data row by row to specific columns. After each process I will have a data like this

```
{'col1': 'value1', 'col2': 'value2'}
```

and value1 will be on the col1 column and value2 will be on the col2 column in the first row.

After I will have the same thing from the code:

```
{'col1': 'value3', 'col2': 'value4'}
```

The result I would like to see:

| header1 | col1 | header 3 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | value1 | row | value2 |
| Second | value 3 | row | value4 |

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your table and your showing script and `{'col1': 'value1', 'col2': 'value2'}`. Can I ask you about the details of it? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I will fix it @Tanaike

Comment: Is the incoming data (apparently in `result`?) being inserted into any existing row or is it going into a completely new row?  If its a new row, is there any data being included in the header1 and header3 columns in that row, or will the data only be in the col1 and col2 columns?
 Could you maybe give an example of what you expect the Google Sheet to look like after the processing compared to your 'before' version?